# Jquery input value not showing up correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something very simple to just get an input value.

The code looks like this:

```
var $a = $('.custom-amount').val();
$('.custom-amount').on('change', function() {
    alert($a)
})
```

And my input:

```
<div class='custom-amount'>
  <input placeholder='Custom Amount' type='text-area'>
```

For some reason, my alerts are empty.  Does anyone see whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selector to `$('.custom-amount input')`, and get the value **after** the change event is fired, e.g.

```
$('.custom-amount input').on('change', function() {
   var a = $(this).val(); 
   alert(a);
});
```

Right now, you are trying to get the value of a `div`, which won't work. You need to get the value of the input.

**Edit:** also, it looks like you are trying to display a `textarea`. Try replacing this...

```
<input placeholder='Custom Amount' type='text-area'>
```

With this...

```
<textarea placeholder='Custom Amount'></textarea>
```

This may help:

http://jsfiddle.net/d648wxry/

Comment: And -0.25 For copy/pasting the $ signs in the variable names. Fixed it for you though :)

Comment: $ in a variable name is valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is very simple, you are getting the value of the div element. Instead you should retrieve the value of the input element so the 'custom-amount' class must be added to the input.

Also you need to execute the val() method inside the event to get the value updated.

```
var $a = $('.custom-amount');

$('.custom-amount').on('change', function() {
  alert($a.val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cause your div has no value. Change your code to:

```
 var $input = $('.custom-amount input');
 $input.on('change', function() {
    var $a = $input.val();
    alert($a)
 })
```

Comment: @Kypros I can add `$` to variable if i want to, for me it's easier to identify is that variable containing `DOM object` or some other type of value. As for `$a` i left it as author wrote it.

Comment: For `$input` it "looks" good but for `$a`, well not so much but i get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only assign to `$a` outside of the `change` function. This would be more clear if you kept your code lined up better (see the edit I made to your post). This is the right way to do it:

```
$('.custom-amount').on('change', function() {
    var $a = $('.custom-amount').val();
    alert($a)
});
```

Second of all, the class `custom-amount` is assigned to a `<div>` instead of the `<input>` element. You have to select the `<input>` element, not the `<div>`. Change your markup to:

```
<div>
    <input placeholder='Custom Amount' type='text-area' class='custom-amount'>
</div>
```

Comment: It is valid to have a `$` in a variable name. My goal was to make minimal change to OP's code so my changes would be easier to understand. (That is also why I decided to forgo changing the second jQuery selector to `$(this)`.)